# Are 'a line perpendicular to a plane' and `plane perpendicular to a line` the same thing?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I know what a line perpendicular to a plane is, but what I have in my mind as a 'plane perpendicular to a line' would look something like this:

[image: the plane can rotate around the line and the line is essentially an axis]

The plane can rotate around the line and the line is essentially an axis.

Is it right?

Comment: What you drew, according to me, is just a black line that lies in the green plane. I mean, do we agree that the fact that you chose to represent the plane as a rectangle is immaterial?

Comment: You are wrong: a plane is perpendicular to a line if that line is perpendicular to the plane, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure you plotted, shows the case where **a plane contains a line not perpendicular to it** since a plane is **infinite** in all directions. Given a lie, a perpendicular plane is the one that contains two distinct lines perpendicular on the primary one (I assume your intuition of two normal lines is complete).